# Netgear ReadyNAS and Windows Server Backup

Tags: backup, windows-server-2008-r2, netgear

I have several boxes running Windows Server 2008 r2. I have been attempting to use the built-in 'Windows Server Backup' so that each of these servers stores their backups to the readyNAS 1100.

What is strange is that I can do a 'Backup Once' backup and it will work but if I attempt to schedule a backup I get the following error:

[image]

I have tried everything I can think of from changing the security settings of the NAS itself to creating new user accounts and just about everything else I know of. It just makes no sense that the one-time backup works while being unable to create a schedule. Has anyone here ever gotten this to work?

I have no trouble browsing the shares through windows explorer. Another thing of note is that one server running Symantec Backup Exec System Recovery has NO PROBLEMS hitting the share and backing up to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the account that the used to fire off the scheduled backup, it may just be the scheduler service. Chance are, that account is the one that is active and being used to connect to the NAS. If so, creating that account with the same username and password on the NAS should do the trick.